# .net mvc special character output

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

```
string str= "Económico Tecnológico <España> test's"

public IHtmlString Title=>new HtmlString(str);
```

I want only encode:<,>,& and @Model.Title output:

```
Económico Tecnológico &lt;España&gt; test's&amp;test
```

I want to not encode Spanish characters when the view is output, but <,>, & need to be encoded
any way? Thanks

Comment: can you show the code of your view?

Comment: I want to not encode Spanish characters when  view is output, but <,>, & need to be encoded

Comment: @HuijunYang it might help to view the code of your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape("Económico Tecnológico <España> test's");
```

which produces `Económico Tecnológico &lt;España&gt; test&apos;s`